# Ember CLI: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `controller:object`

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

My ember-cli version is 0.2.3. I am getting the following error when I try to run tests.

```
TypeError: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `controller:object`
    at Object.Registry.register (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:12208:15)
    at Object.container.(anonymous function) [as register] (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1905:44)
    at Object.isolatedContainer [as default] (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1946:15)
    at exports.default.klassy.Klass.extend._setupIsolatedContainer (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:2406:52)
    at exports.default.klassy.Klass.extend.setupContainer (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:2312:14)
    at nextStep (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:2300:53)
    at exports.default.klassy.Klass.extend.invokeSteps (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:2305:14)
    at exports.default.klassy.Klass.extend.setup (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:2275:19)
    at Object.qunit.module.setup (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1814:16)
    at runHook (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:3534:20)
```

Any idea on what might be causing this? Looking like a ember-cli internal issue.

I am actually using `v2.3.0-beta.2` of Ember CLI. When you fire it up, it displays v0.2.3 on terminal for some reason.

Ember version is 2.0.

I have a unit test for a model that triggers this. The test is using `moduleFor` rather than `moduleForModel` as my app doesn't use Ember Data.

Comment: Why are you using v0.2.3? What's the version of the Ember dependency? What test triggers this?

Comment: @locks Updated my question.

Comment: "I am actually using v2.3.0-beta.2 of Ember CLI. When you fire it up, it displays v0.2.3 on terminal for some reason." That means the project version is different from the system version. Chek the project's `package.json`.

Comment: @locks That fixed my issue. Thanks for your comment. Please add it as an answer.

Comment: done! :) Tried to add a bit more explanation, hope it's useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am actually using v2.3.0-beta.2 of Ember CLI. When you fire it up, it displays v0.2.3 on terminal for some reason.

This happens because your globally installed Ember CLI is different from the version specified in the project's `package.json`.

What Ember CLI does when you run a command if check if it's inside an Ember project. It does this by checking for a `package.json` file in the current, or parent, directory. If it finds it, it will then delegate the command to the Ember CLI that your project depends on.

This is done to make sure that the commands (generate, build, etc) called are the right version and won't break your application.